# "the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by default" -error while compiling ink smart contract

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract

I am attempting to build a smart contract for an imaginary burger shop. But I keep getting this error when I run the build command.

[image: the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by default]

The test compiles, and `cargo check` compiles successfully too.

Here is the source code.

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[ink::contract]
mod burger_shop {

    use ink::prelude::*;
    use ink::storage::Mapping;
    use scale::{Decode, Encode};

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct BurgerShop {
        orders: Vec<(u32, Order)>,
        orders_mapping: Mapping<u32, Order>,
        shop_owner: AccountId,
    }

    // TODO: add logic to calculate gas fees for user

    #[derive(Encode, Decode, Debug, Clone)]
    #[cfg_attr(
        feature = "std",
        derive(scale_info::TypeInfo, ink::storage::traits::StorageLayout)
    )]
    pub struct Order {
        burger_menu: String,
        customer: AccountId,
        price: u32,
        amount: u32,
        paid: bool,
        delivered: bool,
        status: Status,
        completed: bool,
    }

    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub enum Error {
        /// Provide a detailed comment on the error
        PaymentError,
        OrderNotCompleted,
    }

    // result type
    pub type Result<T> = core::result::Result<T, Error>;

    #[cfg_attr(
        feature = "std",
        derive(scale_info::TypeInfo, ink::storage::traits::StorageLayout)
    )]
    #[derive(Encode, Decode, Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
    pub enum Status {
        GettingIngredients,
        Preparing,
        SentForDelivery,
        Delivered,
    }

    impl Default for Status {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Status::GettingIngredients
        }
    }

    impl BurgerShop {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            let list_of_orders = Mapping::new();
            Self {
                orders: vec![],
                orders_mapping: list_of_orders,
                shop_owner: Self::env().caller(),
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_orders(&self) -> Vec<(u32, Order)> {
            // ensure the call is from the shop owner
            let caller = self.env().caller();
            assert!(caller == self.shop_owner, "You are not the shop owner!");
            self.orders.clone()
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn new_order(&mut self, order: Order) {
            let count = self.orders.len() as u32;
            // ensure order is from the customer
            let caller = self.env().caller();
            assert!(caller == order.customer, "You are not the customer!");

            // ensure that the order is not completed
            assert!(
                order.completed == false,
                "Cant add an already completed order!"
            );

            self.orders_mapping.insert(count, &order);

            self.orders.push((count, order));
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_single_order(&self, id: u32) -> (u32, Order) {
            let tuple_order = (id, self.orders_mapping.get(id).expect("Order not found!"));
            tuple_order
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn mark_completed(&mut self, id: u32) -> Result<()> {
            let mut order = self.orders_mapping.get(id).expect("order not found!");

            assert!(order.completed == false, "Order already completed!");
            assert!(order.paid == true, "Order not paid!");
            assert!(order.delivered == true, "Order not delivered!");
            assert!(order.status == Status::Delivered, "Order not delivered!");

            if order.paid && order.delivered && order.status == Status::Delivered {
                order.completed = true;
                Ok(())
            } else {
                Err(Error::OrderNotCompleted)
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn make_payment(&mut self, id: u32) -> Result<()> {
            let mut order = self.orders_mapping.get(id).expect("order not found!");
            assert!(order.paid == false, "Order already paid!");

            // ensure that sender is the caller
            let caller = self.env().caller();
            assert!(caller == order.customer, "You are not the customer!");

            // ensure that the order is not completed
            assert!(order.completed == false, "Order already completed!");

            // ensure that the order is not delivered
            assert!(order.delivered == false, "Order already delivered!");

            // make payment
            match self.env().transfer(self.shop_owner, order.price.into()) {
                Ok(_) => {
                    order.paid = true;
                    order.status = Status::Preparing;
                    Ok(())
                }
                Err(_) => Err(Error::PaymentError),
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn change_status(&mut self, id: u32, status: Status) {
            let mut order = self.orders_mapping.get(id).expect("order not found!");

            // ensure caller is the shop owner
            let caller = self.env().caller();
            assert!(caller == self.shop_owner, "You are not the shop owner!");

            // ensure that the order is not completed
            assert!(order.completed == false, "Order already completed!");

            order.status = status;
        }
    }


    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {
        use super::*;

        #[ink::test]
        fn it_works() {
            let mut burger_shop = BurgerShop::new();
            let order = Order {
                burger_menu: "Cheese Burger".to_string(),
                customer: AccountId::from([0x01; 32]),
                price: 100,
                amount: 1,
                paid: false,
                delivered: false,
                status: Status::GettingIngredients,
                completed: false,
            };

            burger_shop.new_order(order.clone());

            let orders = burger_shop.get_orders();
            assert_eq!(orders.len(), 1);
        }
    }

}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Here is the Cargo.toml file

```toml
[package]
name = "burger_shop"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Ayomide Bajo <oluwashinabajo@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.0.1", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
sp-io = "22.0.0"

[dev-dependencies]
ink_e2e = "4.0.1"

[lib]
path = "lib.rs"

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
]
ink-as-dependency = []
e2e-tests = []
```

The `rustup update && rustup default nightly && cargo build --release` run successfully but `cargo contract build` still results in the same error

This is weird.  `cargo build` compiles but `cargo contract build` doesn't. [image: rustup update && rustup default nightly && cargo build --release]

If `cargo contract build` command doesn't work for my smart contract I can't deploy it.

Comment: Could you share Cargo.toml as well? I suspect some std features are not properly excluded. Or forgetting default-feature = false setting

Comment: Okay, @Shunsuke I just shared the .toml file

Comment: I do manage to compile your code without any problem. I used both the stable and nightly versions of the rust compiler. Would you mind to include the full output of the following command?

`rustup update && rustup default nightly && cargo build --release`

Comment: Thanks @JoséMolina, the command works and compiles. but `cargo contract build` still gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `sp-io = "22.0.0"` from `cargo.toml`. It is not used and it is causing a dependency conflict. After that `cargo contract build` should work.

If you run into more errors, try cleaning the build with the following:

```sh
$ cargo clean && cargo build --release && cargo contract build --release
```

Comment: Thanks!, but now I get a new error lol

Comment: Which one you get? Did you cleanup your build and re-run it after making the change?

Comment: Yeah, I ran `cargo clean` to clean up and remove the target directory

Comment: Please run `cargo clean && cargo build --release && cargo contract build --release`. It did work for me.

Comment: Thank you!
Switching to Rustc stable version solved the last error.

Answer (score 1):

I checked my Rustc compiler version, turns out I was using the nightly+ version which contains some unstable updates for compiling to WASM(I guess).

After switching to the stable version. This fixed the last weird error and it worked. Thanks, guys!